# Border radius on table row doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm making the background of my table rows have rounded corner. Here is the CSS:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> first cell </td>
        <td> middle cell </td>
        <td> third cell </td>
    </tr>
</table>

tr:hover {
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
tr:hover td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

tr:hover td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RzKbq/86/)

It works just fine on Chrome:

[image]

but it doesn't work on Firefox:

[image]

What did I do wrong and how can I fix it on Firefox?

Comment: works in firefox 36.0.4

Comment: I'm on Firefox 37.0.1 (just updated) and it doesn't work, as in the picture. I think it didn't work on my Firefox 36 before, either.

Comment: Firefox 37 but on which OS are you testing it?

Comment: It works well also on Firefox 37 on Linux...

Comment: Before the edit just now it worked fine. In [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/RzKbq/86/) you’re applying the yellow background to the `tr` and not the `td`s and in Firefox the `tr` apparently can’t have rounded corners.

Comment: your updated code work on chorm but no on fiefox

Comment: It's 2021, version 92 and STILL DOESN'T WORK!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are splitting the style on 2 elements, and FF doesn't understand that.

The background is on the tr, and the rounded corners on the td

posible solution: apply the background on the td

```css
body {
    margin: 100px;
}

td {
    padding: 10px;
}

tr:hover td {
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
tr:hover td:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

tr:hover td:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> first cell </td>
        <td> middle cell </td>
        <td> third cell </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: applying the background color on td works fine for me.